# How to get the page leaving event in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I mage my UWP page to be Singleton mode. So that I cannot use function `Navigate()` to navigate to this singleton page. The `Navigate()` function's replacement method is as below.

```
 this.Frame.Content = new BlankPage2();
 Window.Current.Activate();
```

But with this way, when we leaving a page, the `OnNavigatingFrom()` of the page will not be called. But I need an event to tell me whether a page is leaving. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an unusual design decision, but in any case, you are able to get notified on when the `Frame.Content` property changes:

```
var token = rootFrame.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(
               Frame.ContentProperty, 
               ContentChanged);
```

The `ContentChanged` method can look like this:

```
private void ContentChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    //do something when Content changes
}
```

The `token` variable above can be used to unregister the property change notification later:

```
rootFrame.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(Frame.ContentProperty, token);
```